# What does -1.#IND000 mean in the Visual Studio debug window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

In the Visual Studio 2010 watch window, I found the value of a variable became -1.#IND000. What does this mean?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

IND is the representation of NaN (Not a Number) in Windows system. IND = "indeterminate form", mostly a result from an illegal operation like dividing by zero or arithmetic operation with infinity.

Comment: Thanks very much. It turns out the argument for acos() ran out of [-1, +1];

Answer (score 3):

It means the content is undefined, can result from a division by 0.